# Angular JS apply filter conditionally

Tags: angularjs

Avg Product and Channel Pricing : {{average_price | currency}}

The average_price is a string and its initial value is 'None'. It cant be 0.0.

When I apply currency filter, initially the value 'None' is not displayed.

I want the currency filter should be applied only when the average_price is in currency/number format.

Comment: Just check if it's NaN:  `{{ isNaN(average_price) ? average_price : average_price | currency }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a condition.

```
{{(average_price | currency) || average_price}}
```

Or you can give default value if value is invalid for `currency` filter

```
{{(average_price | currency) || 'Not Given'}}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/zimudi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: I have tried the same thing it has not worked. Initially it does not display any thing but when the value it gets is in correct format then it displays with currency format.